# Python - Booting program SuperCollider with a file

Tags: python, supercollider

I am attempting to write an automated startup system for the FoxDot module in python using supercollider.

My main problem right now is when I run the following code:

```
if(running == False):
        startup = thisdir+"/FoxDot/startup.scd" #the location where my startup file is
        subprocess.Popen([sclangloc], 0, startup, cwd=ourcwd, shell=True, ) #boot program with file containing arguments (FoxDot.start)
```

However, when I actually run this, the program is starting but never actually tries to run the arguments in my file.

How can I make supercollider (specifically sclang (the server FoxDot uses to function)) run with said arguments?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

The string-concatenation may be the problem: `thisdir+"/FoxDot/.."` inserts a space before `/FoxDot`. This space is not inserted when using `thisdir++"/..`.